# How to start video using intent android

Tags: android

I am trying to start the video media type using intents. I am completely new to this. I would appreciate a heads up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Intent tostart = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
tostart.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(movieurl), "video/*");
startActivity(tostart);
```